# RequestToJoinLeaveEmailSetting is not being set properly in sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint, powershell, sharepoint-2010

Using object model I am updating group. The value I am setting in 'RequestToJoinLeaveEmailSetting' field is not showing when using PowerShell command. However, when I am fetching it by the object model, it is showing the new value set to 'RequestToJoinLeaveEmailSetting' field.

Using the PowerShell commands I am able to update this field. However, from the object model I am getting the value set from itself, not that is set by PowerShell.

How, can it be in sync? Any help/idea?

Thanks in advanced.
Mohak

Here is my Code:

```
    SPSite Site = new SPSite(siteUrl);
    SPWeb spWeb = Site.OpenWeb();
    SPGroup spGroup = spWeb.SiteGroups[oldname];
    SPRoleCollection roles = spGroup.Roles;
    if (roles != null)
    {
    oldRoles = new ArrayList();
    foreach (SPRole role in roles)
    {
    oldRoles.Add(role.Name);
    }
    }
    // here we are comparing the old and new roles to be updated and separating out
    // which roles to be deleted and which is to be updated.
    foreach (string role in oldRoles)
    {
    if (newRoles.Contains(role))
    {
    updatedRoles.Add(role);
    }
    else
    {
    removeRoles.Add(role);
    }
    }
    foreach (string rolenames in newRoles)
    {
    if (!oldRoles.Contains(rolenames))
    {
    updatedRoles.Add(rolenames);
   }
   }
   if (removeRoles != null && removeRoles.Count > 0)
   {
   SPRoleAssignment roleAssignment = new SPRoleAssignment(spGroup);
   foreach (string str in removeRoles)
   {
   SPRoleDefinition role = spWeb.RoleDefinitions[str];
   //SPRoleAssignment roleAssignment = new SPRoleAssignment(spGroup);
   roleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings.Remove(role);
   spWeb.RoleAssignments.Remove(roleAssignment.Member);
   spWeb.Update();
   }
   spWeb.Update();
   }
   if (spGroup != null)
   {
   spGroup.Description = description;
   spGroup.Name = name;
   spGroup.OnlyAllowMembersViewMembership = viewprmsn;
   spGroup.AllowMembersEditMembership = edprmsn;
   spGroup.AllowRequestToJoinLeave = mbrrqst;
   spGroup.AutoAcceptRequestToJoinLeave = acptrqst;
   spGroup.RequestToJoinLeaveEmailSetting = emailid;               

   if (updatedRoles != null && updatedRoles.Count > 0)
   SPRoleAssignment roleAssignment = new SPRoleAssignment(spGroup);
   // SPRoleDefinition roleDefinition = spWeb.RoleDefinitions["Contribute"];
   foreach (string str in updatedRoles)
   {
   SPRoleDefinition roleDefinition = spWeb.RoleDefinitions[str];
   roleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings.Add(roleDefinition);
   }
   spWeb.RoleAssignments.Add(roleAssignment);
   }
   //spGroup.RequestToJoinLeaveEmailSetting = emailid;
   spGroup.Update();
   }
   spWeb.Update();
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
   SPTlogger.Error("-------------------------ERROR-------------------------");
   SPTlogger.Error("Error in UpdateGroup():" + ex.Message);
   throw new Exception(ex.Message);
   }
   finally
   {
   SPTlogger.Debug("<-- : UpdateGroup()");
   }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you forgot to apply changes using [SPGroup.Update method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spgroup.update.aspx) when the group properties have been updated

PS example:

```
$web = Get-SPWeb $webUrl
$membersGroup = $web.AssociatedMemberGroup
$membersGroup.RequestToJoinLeaveEmailSetting = "admin@intranet.contoso.com"
$membersGroup.Update() #save group changes
```